# Is there a way to web scrape & download the videos on an Amazon Product page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, video

I am looking for some help with scraping product videos from any Amazon Product page.

For example, the videos in the red box below:

[product videos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHZVw.png)
[amazon product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D6Nb.png)

I've searched quite extensively for help on the Internet for answers but they don't address this issue.

Usually, there would be file an src with a .mp4 extension that we can use as the url to download, but in this case, the src seems to be a "blob" link.

For example, in the product above, to play the first video in the red box, we need to click it and a video player will be opened up, as shown below:

[video player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZgu5.png)

Inspecting the video player shows the following:
[video player inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJizV.png)

The src of the video is: blob:https://www.amazon.com/bb93cc83-5768-4eb9-a10d-f6a889e5a832

Simply pasting this into the address bar yields "Your file couldn't be accessed", as shown below:
[Your file couldn't be accessed message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lhhb.png)

Removing "blob" from the beginning of the url, so the it's just: https://www.amazon.com/bb93cc83-5768-4eb9-a10d-f6a889e5a832, and pasting this into the address bar yields "Page not found", as show below:
[page not found message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Ovm.png)

There's not even an iframe tag that may somehow have the .mp4 URL.

Another possible method I thought of is to somehow use Internet Download Manager to download the videos in my Python script, but from what I can gather, it seems like I would still need the .mp4 url to use the Internet Download Manager API, which does not seem to be available on the Amazon pages.

Comment: I do not think so web-scraping is possible for amazon. Maybe it might almost be like stealing their data. If it is legal then, you can use `beautiful soup` or `Selenium` packages for web scraping

Comment: Yes I am using BeautifulSoup and Selenium to get the product information such as the Product Name, price, ASIN etc. But I am stuck at downloading the videos, as the way Amazon pages are structured, they don't put the video source in a .mp4 URL, instead they use this "blob" data.  I need help downloading the videos given that the video source is a "blob" instead of a .mp4 URL. Thanks again.

Comment: Just thought I'd circle back to this for anyone else facing the same issue. I think I've discovered the solution. To download a video from an Amazon product page, we need to look for m3u8 URL's instead of mp4. From there, we can use FFMPEG to convert it to mp4.

Comment: @yoon dfl using Firefox's web developer tools, I can see the blob entry e.g.  in Debugger tabblob:https://www.amazon.co.uk/7abbc2fd-f0fd-45c8-96ef-7ce13fa37b5b
but I don't see any m3u8 or mp4 in it. Please give a specific example or fuller instructions.

Answer (score -3):

View page source in chrome and search for mp4, you will get video urls.